# CGContextDrawPDFPage occasional crash in font render code

Tags: ios, crash

I have a PDF reader application that displays several UIViewControllers with a PDF layer in a UIScrollView.

What i am experiencing is occasional crashes when the user swipes though the scroll view. Fabric always points to a part of code that looks like the font renderer. The strange thing is that it only happens sometimes even if the user swipes to the same PDF page that crashed previously. There are also also no leaks or overreleased object crashes related to the PDF.

Any ideas of what could be causing this? Thanks

Here is an example crash:

```
#3. Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos
0  libFontParser.dylib            0x2467fef8 TType1Font::GetGlyphsPerCharacters(unsigned short const*, unsigned short*, unsigned int&, bool) const + 211
1  libFontParser.dylib            0x2466e45d TFPFont::GetXHeightAndCapHeightByAverageGlyphHeights(FPFontInfo&) const + 72
2  libFontParser.dylib            0x2466e45d TFPFont::GetXHeightAndCapHeightByAverageGlyphHeights(FPFontInfo&) const + 72
3  libFontParser.dylib            0x2466d4c7 TFPFont::FillFontInfo(TFPFontInfo&) const + 762
4  libFontParser.dylib            0x2466d149 TFPFont::GetFontInfo() const + 108
5  libFontParser.dylib            0x2466d0c9 FPFontIsMonospaced + 8
6  CoreGraphics                   0x2386cf31 get_font_info + 208
7  CoreGraphics                   0x2381bbe9 get_font_info + 36
8  CoreGraphics                   0x2381bc1d CGFontGetUnitsPerEm + 8
9  CoreGraphics                   0x237f0d53 get_glyph_bounding_box + 22
10 CoreGraphics                   0x237f0a57 draw_glyph_bitmaps + 642
11 CoreGraphics                   0x237efeb3 ripc_DrawGlyphs + 1074
12 CoreGraphics                   0x2381b7f7 draw_glyphs + 834
13 CoreGraphics                   0x2377b811 simple_draw + 220
14 CoreGraphics                   0x2377b59f CGPDFTextLayoutDrawGlyphs + 74
15 CoreGraphics                   0x236de265 op_Tj + 48
16 CoreGraphics                   0x238b02f9 pdf_scanner_handle_xname + 72
17 CoreGraphics                   0x238afe6d CGPDFScannerScan + 384
18 CoreGraphics                   0x238b6f83 CGPDFDrawingContextDrawPage + 390
19 CoreGraphics                   0x236d411f pdf_page_draw_in_context + 86
20 CoreGraphics                   0x235e8c37 CGContextDrawPDFPage + 38
21 ------                         0x256635 -[----- drawLayer:inContext:] (------.m:107)
22 QuartzCore                     0x24bfc325 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 228
23 QuartzCore                     0x24ce7017 tiled_layer_render(_CAImageProvider*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*) + 1454
24 QuartzCore                     0x24c2ab99 CAImageProviderThread(unsigned int*, bool) + 472
25 libdispatch.dylib              0x2211f6a1 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1572
26 libdispatch.dylib              0x2211f07b _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 94
27 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x222b2e0d _pthread_wqthread + 1024
28 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x222b29fc start_wqthread + 8
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a fix for this. As mentioned, our app drew several PDFs concurrently when the user was swiping.

So it turned out that moving the PDF drawing code (all CGContext.. calls) of all instances from 
`drawLayer:(CALayer*)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context`
to a shared serial queue fixed the issue.